# SilverLight Service Deployment

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

I've written a silverlight app with a simple wcf service. Runs great on my computer, when I publish it to my web account it no longer works with the service. I tried editing the clintconfig file to set the endpoint to the new location, that did not fix it. So I downloaded this simple SilverLight App with WCF example setup for deploying, and it also works on my personal machine, but not when I publish it to my domain. My account supports asp.net, wcf, etc.. The link to the example I downloaded: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152778/Deploying-Silverlight-with-WCF-Services

I'm new to this, so I'm wondering if this is something that should work without additional work, or if I'm missing something. I'm not getting any errors, I'm just not getting the message displayed on the screen from the service.

Added following after Hatchets Comment:
I'm trying to figure out how to find a error message. So far the only way I know it's not working is I don't see the message that is returned from the service. SilverLight displays the returned message, "Hello from My WCF Service". I see it on my machine, but not when I publish it to my domain. The app I downloaded, if I understand it right, is setup to work without having to change the endpoint address, but i'm so new to this, I've not figured out what i'm missing yet.
Thanks.

Added after comments below:

I grabed fiddler, and after i added the  tag, i was able to see an error in fiddler, and when browsing to the .svc file. Error:

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'multipleSiteBindingsEnabled'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

```
Source Error: 


Line 30:         </bindings>
Line 31:         <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
Line 32:             multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
Line 33:         <services>
Line 34:             <service name="testWCF.Web.Service1">
```

Source File: \boswinfs03\home\users\web\b706\whl.forystpcom\web.config    Line: 32

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4211; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4016

I'm unfamiliar with multipleSiteBindingsEnabled and the best way to handle this, does the version of .NET running affect this? The server i'm running this on supports up to 3.5 it says, but I notice it quotes version 2.0 in the error, not sure if they are connected.

Comment: there are a few hoops to jump through, but we'd need to know HOW it is failing to have an idea which hoop is the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to find a error message. So far the only way I know it's not working is I don't see the message that is returned from the service. SilverLight displays the returned message, "Hello from My WCF Service". I see it on my machine, but not when I publish it to my domain. The app I downloaded, if I understand it right, is setup to work without having to change the endpoint address, but i'm so new to this, I've not figured out what i'm missing yet.

Comment: Try enabling some networking tracing tool such as Fiddler, then see what request the SL app is sending to the server, then see if there is anything wrong in the response.

Comment: You say that you are publishing it to your domain. Is this a hosting provider, or is it your own server? If it is a hosting provider you may want to check with them that WCF is installed and supported on the machine. If it is your own server, you could try installing/reinstalling WCF yourself. More info on that here:  
http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/04/23/deploying-wcf-service-in-iis-no-svc-mime-type/

Comment: Oh, and as for getting to the error message, try browsing to the .svc file and see if that gives you any error messages.

Comment: I've posted my comment to the end or my original question, to many characters for this space.

Comment: I'd sent a message off to my hosting provider to insure they did support wcf as stated on plan, and they do, but they only support up to 3.5, and Tsabo stated below that MultipleSitesBindingEnabled is a 4.0 update, so I'm going to setup my app as 3.5 and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I know the example you're following is not RIA Services, and this link is, but it may be helpful as it goes over some common Silverlight/WCF services deployment problems

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2010/03/16/ria-services-application-deployment.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MultipleSitesBindingEnabled is part of the 4.0 update, so it can not run on a server that supports up to 3.5. You need to configure your service to use a specific endpoint(s).

Sourse: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicehostingenvironmentsection.multiplesitebindingsenabled.aspx)

P.S. When browsing to the .svc, it will say that .net 2.0 is installed for anything from 2.0 - 3.5 , but then 4.0 is installed it will say 4.0.

Comment: Thanks, My domain provider did come back and let me know they only support up to 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not considering this the answer, just thought it was a cleaner place to put an update. My first problem was my program was using 4.0 and my provider did not support 4.0. My 2nd problem was: This collection already contains an address with scheme http. There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.Parameter name: item" , I found a fix for this at: http://www.j2i.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/08/This-collection-already-contains-an-address-with-scheme-http-There-can-be-at-most-one-address-per-scheme-in-this-collectionParameter-name-item.aspx
I was able to fix this by adding the following code.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="http://www.mydomain.com" />
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Thanks to all the Help everyone. Thanks for  carlosfigueira for the suggestion to download the fiddler app. If you want to repost that suggestion to a answer I'll check it, as it helped me figure out the errors I was getting, leading to solving the problem.